# Converting NSString to uint8_t to appendBytes:length

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, byte, nsdata

I need to convert an `NSString` or an `int` so that I can use NSData to appendBytes:length.

From

```
@"734" or 734
```

to

```
uint8_t _steps[2];
_steps[0] = 0x02;
_steps[1] = 0xde;
[_data appendBytes:_steps length:2];
```

### Example

```
- (void)sendSteps:(NSString*)steps
{
    NSMutableData *_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Need to get (NSString*)steps converted like below:
    uint8_t _steps[2];
    _steps[0] = 0x02;
    _steps[1] = 0xde;

    [_data appendBytes:_steps length:2];
}
```

### What I've tried

```
NSData * _steps = [(NSString*)activity[@"steps"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_data appendBytes:[_steps bytes] length:[_steps length]];
```

and

```
uint8_t * _steps = (uint8_t *)[(NSString*)activity[@"steps"] UTF8String];
[_data appendBytes:_steps length:strlen((char*)_steps)];
```

### Desired result

The desired result for "`734`" is **`02de`**.

Answer (score 1):

The code you want is

```
int stepsIntValue = [(NSString*)activity[@"steps"] intValue];

uint8_t _steps[2];
_steps[0] = (stepsIntValue >> 8) & 0xFF;
_steps[1] = stepsIntValue & 0xFF;

[_data appendBytes:_steps length:2];
```

I don't understand the practical use.

Are you only going to pull 2 bytes ever? If so then why not use `htons(3)`

```
uint16_t _steps = htons([(NSString*)activity[@"steps"] intValue]);
[_data appendBytes:&_steps length:sizeof _steps];
```

When you pull data out, you can use `ntohs(3)`.

```
_steps = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)[_data bytes]);
```